# Manejor de error global Python

Tags: python, selenium

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de poder manejar cualquier tipo de error que aparezca en el browser de manera tal que dentro de mi función Connections(url) cualquier objeto no encontrado por el `ccs_selector` en vez de cortarme el programa vuelva a ejecutar desde el principio `def connections.`

Habia pensado algo asi:

```
try:
    a = 12
    b = 13
    c = 14
except:
    run(a)
```

Se que no existe eso que escribi pero es a manera de graficar lo que busco. Si por cualquier motivo no puedo generarse a = 12, b = 13, c = 14  volve a intentarlo! En el caso de mi codigo seria si cualquier accion dentro de def no pudo concretarse volver a ejecutar def

```
def Connections(url):
    df = pd.read_excel(">0.20 fillrate.xlsx", header = None,  converters={0: str}).pivot(columns = 0,  values = 1)
    Lista = {col: df[col].dropna().tolist() for col in df.columns}
    for id,  tags in Lista.iteritems():
        urlcn = driver.get(url.format(id.strip()))
        driver.refresh()
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".navbar-inhiner > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.navbar-inhiner > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)').click()
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.ng-scope:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")    
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.ng-scope:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)').click()
    #Cargado de tags
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ng-scope:nth-child(12) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.ng-scope:nth-child(12) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').click()
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#s2id_autogen30"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")    
    nombre = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#s2id_autogen30')
    for tag in tags:
        nombre.send_keys(tag)
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.select2-results-dept-0'))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
        except TimeoutException:
                print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        try:
            nombre2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.select2-results-dept-0').click()
        except:
            pass
            nombre.clear()
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn-success:nth-child(3)').click()
        except:
            pass
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
    #Guardado de la connection
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".bs-docs-social-buttons > li:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    d= driver.current_url
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".bs-docs-social-buttons > li:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)").click()
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "adap-marketplace-connections-grid-filter.ng-scope > button:nth-child(1)"))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    print(d)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar por defecto

```
try:
    int("y")
except Exception as error:
    print("Ha ocurrido un error: ", repr(error))
    run(10)
```

Es bueno imprimir el error para saber que es lo que esta mal.

Y lo que escribiste si se puede hacer incluso puedes combinarlo con un reintento por ejemplo:

```
for i in range(5):
    try:
        kilometros = calcular_kilomentros(puntos)
        if kilometros != 0:
            break
    except Exception as error:
        print (" Error : ", repr(error))
```

Este código reintenta 5 veces , si lo hace a la primera simplemente continua.

Por ejemplo si lo que quieres es que cuando falle por cualquier error, intente hasta 5 veces deberás hacer esto.

```
def Connections(url): 
    variables = [10,11,13,14,15]
    cont = 0
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            # aqui ira todo tu código 
            #ejemplo 
            run(variables[cont])
            cont +=1   # con esto si por ejemplo falla cuando vas ejecutando run(11), cuando reintente ejecutara run(variables[cont]), que sería igual a run(11) otra vez, es decir continua donde iba 
            break  #para que termine si no hay errores
        except Exception as error:
            print (" Error : ", repr(error))
```

para que funcione deberás no capturar los errores con todos los `try` que tienes, a menos que sean necesarios.

Espero te sirva. saludos

Comment: puedo hacerlo asi? `def Connections(url):
    df = pd.read_excel(">0.20 fillrate.xlsx", header = None,  converters={0: str}).pivot(columns = 0,  values = 1)
    Lista = {col: df[col].dropna().tolist() for col in df.columns}
    for id,  tags in range(5), Lista.iteritems():
        urlcn = driver.get(url.format(id.strip()))
        driver.refresh()`

Comment: He editado la respuesta, por favor revisa.

Comment: funciona a la perfecion, la unica pregunta que tengo es la siguiente, yo mi codigo lo hago correr y voy modificando valores de una lista, por ejemplo que mi lista tiene 10 valores y va por el 3ro, se produce un error y arranca de nuevo. Como hago para hacer que arranque desde el valor que tuvo un error y no desde el 1ero??

Comment: no se como se hace, me podrias mostrar?

Comment: Mira otra vez la respuesta, creo que mas no puedo hacer.

Comment: no tengo definido run, como hago?? me quedo todo bien armado menos lo del run

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68075/discussion-between-edwin-cubillos-and-martin-bouhier).